# lookAt with orthographic camera (gl-matrix)

Tags: opengl, camera, matrix, webgl

Technically this is a webgl question though I think it's generic enough to get some opengl, erm, perspective on it too...

If I setup an orthographic camera (**perspective** matrix) like this:

`mat4.ortho(output, 0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 0, 1)`

And compose it with an identity matrix as the **view**, and then compose my **model** matrix with that - everything is fine and I see the items at the correct size on the screen. However, if instead of using an identity matrix as the *view* I use `lookAt` via:

`mat4.lookAt(output, [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0])`

I do not see anything. I've tried some other variations like moving the `eye` parameter from `[0,0,0]` to `[0,0,-1]` and increasing the `far` value of `ortho()` but nothing worked.

What exactly *is* the relationship between `lookAt` and `ortho` - are they compatible for `perspective`x`view`, if so what settings can I use for `lookAt` such that it works correctly here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When I use the identity view matrix, I can see my model, but when I use `LookAt`, it is not visible. How can I see my model using `LookAt`?

The `LookAt` function takes three parameters:

- `eye`, which is where your camera is. in the identity matrix, your camera is at `0, 0, 0`
- `target`, which is where your camera is pointed at. you can think of the camera's direction vector as `target - eye`. In the identity matrix, the camera is facing in the direction of the negative Z axis.
- `up`, which is which way your camera is rotated. `0, 1, 0` is the default `up` in the usual coordinate system.

In order to replicate your identity view matrix, just use `mat4.lookat(.., [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 1, 0])`.

If the above works, now you can experiment with changing the `eye` parameter to move the camera around.

> If I set up an ortho camera like this: `mat4.ortho(output, 0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 0, 1)`, things go wrong.

Those parameters dont' look right to me. it should be `mat4.ortho(output, -scaleX, scaleX, -scaleY, scaleY, 0, farZ)` . Depending on your coordinates and aspect ratio, the values of `scaleX` and `scaleY` are roughly half the distance between your camera and target to get a similar scale of view to the perspective camera. If you have no ideal, start scaleX and scaleY off at 1. additionally, farZ = 1 is a very short range, you may want to raise it up much higher, especially if you're moving the camera around.

#### Playground

I've included a basic "rotating camera around a triangle" demo here, the left side is a perspective projection, the right side is an ortho projection. Feel free to play with the `distance` variable and see how the scale for the ortho changes in proportion to the perspective shrinking as the camera is further away.

```js
cv.width = window.innerWidth;
cv.height = window.innerHeight;
var gl = cv.getContext('webgl');
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

function Mesh(arr) {
  var buf = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(arr), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  return buf;
}
var mesh = Mesh([0.0, 1.0, -0,-1.0, -1.0, -0,1.0, -1.0, -0 ])

function shader(type, src) { 
  var s = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(s, src);
  gl.compileShader(s);
  return s
}
var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, shader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `
attribute vec3 pos; 
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main() { gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(pos, 1); }
`));
gl.attachShader(program, shader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1); }"));
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.validateProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program)
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program, 0);
function render(viewport, proj_mat, view_mat) { 
    gl.viewport.apply(gl, viewport);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'projection'), false, proj_mat)
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'view'), false, view_mat)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
var view = mat4.create();
var ortho_proj = mat4.create();
var perspective_proj = mat4.create();
var fov = 0.7, distance = 4;
var scale = Math.tan(fov / 2) * distance; // since ortho is distance invariant, scale by (distance from camera to some reference point)

function loop(t) { 
t /= 1000;
mat4.perspective(perspective_proj, fov, 1, 0.1, 1000.0);
mat4.ortho(ortho_proj, -scale, scale, -scale, scale, 0.1, 100);
mat4.lookAt(view, [distance * Math.sin(t),0, distance * Math.cos(t)],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]);

render([0, 0, cv.width / 2, cv.height], perspective_proj, view);
render([cv.width / 2, 0, cv.width / 2, cv.height], ortho_proj, view);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();
```

```css
body, html { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
canvas { background: #39e; position:absolute; top:0px; }
h2, h3 { position:absolute; top:0px; z-index: 20; }
.r { right:0px; }
```

```html
<h2>Perspective</h2>
<h2 class=r>Ortho</h2>
<canvas id=cv> </canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.4.0/gl-matrix.js"></script>
```

---

### Obsolete Answer

This first answer to a supposed question "what, in the general sense, is the relationship between an ortho and a lookAt matrix?".

There's 3 kinds of matrices that combine to form a full transformation:

the **model** matrix, which describes the transformation applied to the vertices of your model to get them into world-space,

the **view** matrix, which describes the transformation to get from your world-space into a camera-relative space (eye coordinates),

the **perspective** matrix to describe how to transform the camera-space positions into how it appears on your screen (clip-space / screen-space after the perspective correction).

In your case, `ortho` and `perspective` are ways to create the perspective matrix, and `lookAt` creates a view matrix (you could also manually create a view matrix by combining a bunch of mat4.translate/rotate/scales to re-create the camera position).

Your final transform must multiply the perspective * view * model matrices.

Comment: Oh, my mistake - I thought that was implied in my original question but I see that it wasn't. I've now edited to clarify my question in this context, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @davidkomer I've added an explanation for what I think your question is: (what is the identity `lookAt` parameters?) See if that is more helpful.